# Have Babel transpile modules referenced in source files?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler, ecma

I hoped Babel would transpile both my source and the modules referenced in the source, but it does not.

```
module.exports = {
    ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!@polymer|@webcomponents)/],
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@webcomponents|@polymer)\/)/,
    test: /(src|node_modules\/@polymer)/,

    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', {
        allowTopLevelThis: true
        }]
    ],

    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
        debug: true,
        targets: {
            node: 6
        }
        }]
    ]
};
```

Running against this:

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element';
import 'fs';
console.log('hello, world', PolymerElement, html);
```

Output:

```
[temp 13:25:29] babel --copy-files --ignore ^\.\/node_modules --config-file ./babel.config.js  ./src -o ./dist/index.js; cat dist/index.js
@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{
"node": "6"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
    transform-function-name { "node":"6" }
    transform-for-of { "node":"6" }
    transform-dotall-regex { "node":"6" }
    transform-destructuring { "node":"6" }
    transform-exponentiation-operator { "node":"6" }
    transform-async-to-generator { "node":"6" }
    proposal-async-generator-functions { "node":"6" }
    proposal-object-rest-spread { "node":"6" }
    proposal-unicode-property-regex { "node":"6" }
    proposal-json-strings { "node":"6" }
    proposal-optional-catch-binding { "node":"6" }

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.

"use strict";

var _polymerElement = require("@polymer/polymer/polymer-element");

require("fs");

console.log('hello, world', _polymerElement.PolymerElement, _polymerElement.html);
```

Comment: It seems there's a discrepancy between the debugger output and your config. In your config you tell it to only ignore `[/node_modules\/(?!@polymer|@webcomponents)/]` but in the debugger it says `--ignore ^\.\/node_modules`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the capturing you're doing in the regex. Try passing in multiple patterns instead of one:

`[/node_modules\/@polymer/, /node_modules\/@webcomponents/]`

Comment: Aren't you only targeting the directory and not the files? What happens if you broaden the regex in `test` like: `(src|node_modules\/@polymer).+\.(j|t)sx?` (in this example to target every `.ts`, `.tsx`, `.js` and `.jsx`) inside `node_modules`